# How to make writeonly property in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I need an `writeonly` property in objective-c, but I don't know how to do it. I did not find description if it is ever possible.

So, is it possible to create `writeonly` property in objective-c?

**EDIT:**

Actually I need to pass that `NSArray` from one `View controller` to another one, using segue. I want to avoid confusion to use that property in the wrong place in the code.

May be this is not the best solution, but I come to that one. If there are better, let me know. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: why do you need that??? what's wrong with reading the written value???

Comment: What is a `writeOnly` property? i.e. what would it be used for if you could write it but not read it?

Comment: In other programming languages there can be a property which only can be set, but not get. @Fogmeister, I came to objective-c from MS development. May be I did not get yet the conception of objective-c and may be my question is stupid. I need that for array that I need to process in advance. I want to avoid confusion using data from that array somewhere in the code except in that section.

Comment: Fair enough, I just hadn't come across that concept before. I think the answer is correct though. Don't create a property, just create a "setter" method.

Comment: Yes, @Fogmeister. The answer is perfect. That is exactly what I need.

Comment: I put edit on my question, @Andrey Chernukha, to explain why I need that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with declared Properties. But you can simply (solely) add a declaration for a setter in the interface.

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject
- (void)setWriteOnlyProperty:(id)value;
@end
```

Addition:

You can still use KVC and dot notation on it. This does not need declared properties. However, it is inconvenient while debugging and if the receiver is `id`-typed.

BTW: What for?

Comment: 10x, @Amin Negm-Awad, I have an NSArray with XML inside, I need to process it and have similar array with processed elements. I don't want to confuse 2 of them somewhere in the code. So I decided that I can create `writeonly` property to avoid confusion.

Comment: I do not understand how write only properties can block the confusion. Obviously I need more information for that. However, good identifiers prevent from that kind of confusions better by far.